# why I cannot multiply an op result by the constant eigen tensor array

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

Why it's not legal to do multiplication of the tensor op(sqrt()) and the linear.constant()

```
Eigen::Tensor<float, 1> linear(2);
linear.setValues({3,4});
auto linear_square = linear * linear;
auto linear_square_sum = linear_square.sum().sqrt(); 
std::cout<<linear_square_sum<<std::endl; // 5

auto new_linear = linear_square_sum * linear.constant(5); //no compiling error but aborted when executing
```

error info

> tensor2matrix:
>   /usr/local/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorEvaluator.h:380:
>   Eigen::TensorEvaluator, Device>::TensorEvaluator(const XprType&,
>   const Device&) [with BinaryOp =
>   Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op; LeftArgType = const
>   Eigen::TensorCwiseUnaryOp,
>   const Eigen::TensorReductionOp,
>   const Eigen::DimensionList, const
>   Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp, const Eigen::Tensor, const Eigen::Tensor
>
> > , Eigen::MakePointer> >; RightArgType = const Eigen::TensorCwiseNullaryOp,
> >     const Eigen::Tensor >; Device = Eigen::DefaultDevice;
> >     Eigen::TensorEvaluator, Device>::XprType =
> >     Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp, const
> >     Eigen::TensorCwiseUnaryOp,
> >     const Eigen::TensorReductionOp,
> >     const Eigen::DimensionList, const
> >     Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp, const Eigen::Tensor, const Eigen::Tensor
> >     , Eigen::MakePointer> >, const Eigen::TensorCwiseNullaryOp,
> >     const Eigen::Tensor > >]: Assertion
> >     `dimensions_match(m_leftImpl.dimensions(), m_rightImpl.dimensions())'
> >     failed. Aborted

Comment: Sorry, which error?

Comment: @S.M.error info updated

Comment: It's clear from the error message: the assertion of dimensions_match failed. Please try to write the multiplication mathematically.

Comment: The multiplication is 5*[5,5] = [25,25]

Comment: Try to change the order of the product arguments: [5, 5] * 5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure people already linked to you the documentation saying that using `auto` with expression templates is not a good idea. Evaluating one expression template multiple times seems like an even worse idea.

If you don't want/can't explicitly mention the types you can base them on the original values you put in.

```
Eigen::Tensor<float, 1> linear(2);
linear.setValues({ 3,4 });
decltype(linear) linear_square = linear * linear;
Eigen::Tensor<decltype(linear)::Scalar, 0> linear_square_sum = linear_square.sum().sqrt();
std::cout << linear_square_sum << std::endl; // 5

//              Don't forget to convert to an actual scalar
//                                             |
//                                             v
decltype(linear) new_linear = linear_square_sum() * linear.constant(5);

std::cout << new_linear;

return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your patient answer. What I wonder is why eigen does not provide the broadcasting of a scalar and tensor while there is broadcasting in the multiplication of vector and matrix [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html). Which I means that 
`(linear * linear).sqrt() *  linear.constant(5)` is legal, while `(linear * linear).sum().sqrt() *  linear.constant(5)` is not. Anyway thank you so much for all the time

Comment: I finally solve the problem by reshape the 0 dimension scalar to one dimension and then broadcast it to 1*2 shape of auto eigen tensor@PeterT